# How to feature-ize timeseries data in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that are structured as below:

```
Group, ID, Time, Feat1, Feat2, Feat3
A, 1, 0, 1.52, 2.94, 3.1
A, 1, 2, 1.67, 2.99, 3.3
A, 1, 4, 1.9, 3.34, 5.6
```

In this data, there are individuals who have been measured repeatedly.

I'd like to restructure the data such that each feature-time combination is a unique column, as below:

```
Group, ID, Feat1_Time0, Feat1_Time2, Feat1_Time4, Feat2_Time0, Feat2_Time2, Feat2_Time4, Feat3_Time0, Feat3_Time2, Feat3_Time4
A, 1, 1.52, 2.94, 3.1, 1.67, 2.99, 3.3, 1.9, 3.34, 5.6
```

Is there a simple way to handle this, without using a for-loop? I've tried accomplishing what I need with the for-loop method, but it is inelegant and clunky, and given real data of 10<sup>4</sup> columns, it would take a while as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'A'},
                   'Time': {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 0, 4: 2, 5: 4},
                   'ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2},
                   'Feat1': {0: 1.52, 1: 1.6699999999999999, 2: 1.8999999999999999, 3: 1.52, 4: 1.6699999999999999, 5: 1.8999999999999999},
                   'Feat3': {0: 3.1000000000000001, 1: 3.2999999999999998, 2: 5.5999999999999996, 3: 3.1000000000000001, 4: 3.2999999999999998, 5: 5.5999999999999996},
                   'Feat2': {0: 2.9399999999999999, 1: 2.9900000000000002, 2: 3.3399999999999999, 3: 2.9399999999999999, 4: 2.9900000000000002, 5: 3.3399999999999999}})

df1 = df.set_index(['Group', 'ID', 'Time']).unstack()
df1
```

[image]

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.to_series().apply(pd.Series).astype(str).T.apply('_'.join)
df1.reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Genius! What if there are other repeated characteristics of each individual, say, a `binary_character` that also gets repeated across each individual? I tried using your code directly, but got an unstacking error - `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, I did try with the synthetic data, no issues. Must be a data issue on my side...

Comment: I'd recommend asking another question because I'd have to see the data.

Comment: I wish I could share the data - it's from the DREAM Respiratory Viral challenge, and there's a strict data sharing embargo on it. :( Either way, thanks for the help :)